# Rails - Find appropriate record in Model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, model, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to pull up a specific table row for one of my MODELS in another MODEL but having difficulties

```
class Volunteer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :volunteerable, polymorphic: true

  def item_quantity_have
    a = Stuff.first
    a.quantity_have
  end

  def item_quantity_given
    self.quantity_given
  end

  def add_em_up
    item_quantity_have + item_quantity_given
  end

  def make_it_happen
    a = Stuff.first
    a.update_attributes(quantity_have: add_em_up)
  end
end
```

this is what i have so far and its working but only posting to the first model in STUFF obviously because im calling

```
Stuff.first
```

but I'm having a hard time trying to find the specific id that it needs to post too....i know in my controller i can do

```
params[:id]
```

but i guess in the model i can't do that....so what can i do to find the appropriate params in my model like i do in my controller?

i want to be able to do something like

```
a = Stuff.find_by_id(:id)
a.quantity_have
```

and pull up that number for that specific id

Comment: Is there some sort of relationship between `Volunteer` and `Stuff`?

Comment: @muistooshort - yes there stuff has_many volunteers and volunteers belongs_to stuff

Comment: Then within a `Volunteer` instance method, you just need `self.stuff` which will be the `stuff` associated with the given `volunteer`.

Comment: @mbratch = thank you for that...learning pains